# CameraSource Exception java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, android, out-of-memory, android-camera

I have an issues on..

> Exception java.lang.OutOfMemoryError:

on the following line..

```
byte[] byteArray = new byte[bufferSize];
```

What should be the cause and how can I prevent it.

**CODE**

```
private byte[] createPreviewBuffer(Size previewSize) {
    int bitsPerPixel = ImageFormat.getBitsPerPixel(ImageFormat.NV21);
    long sizeInBits = previewSize.getHeight() * previewSize.getWidth() * bitsPerPixel;
    int bufferSize = (int) Math.ceil(sizeInBits / 8.0d) + 1;

    //
    // NOTICE: This code only works when using play services v. 8.1 or higher.
    //

    // Creating the byte array this way and wrapping it, as opposed to using .allocate(),
    // should guarantee that there will be an array to work with.
    byte[] byteArray = new byte[bufferSize];
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(byteArray);
    if (!buffer.hasArray() || (buffer.array() != byteArray)) {
        // I don't think that this will ever happen.  But if it does, then we wouldn't be
        // passing the preview content to the underlying detector later.
        throw new IllegalStateException("Failed to create valid buffer for camera source.");
    }
    mBytesToByteBuffer.put(byteArray, buffer);
    return byteArray;
}
```

**CRASH DEVICE INFO**

[image]

Comment: What's the value of `bufferSize`?

Comment: @Carcigenicate actually this code is from https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/blob/master/visionSamples/barcode-reader/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/samples/vision/barcodereader/ui/camera/CameraSource.java from line 1030

Comment: @Carcigenicate I think it's depend on each preview size of android device.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. If you're getting an exception, you must have run the code. What was the value of `bufferSize` when you got the exception?

Comment: There are only to options the heap size is not enough. Or the calculations/conversions prior to that give the wrong values

Comment: @Carcigenicate stacktrace doesn't tell me bufferSize when got an exception. however, I added device info when user got exception.

Comment: @JongzPuangput Just print a log of the size. The error is probably being caused by trying to allocate a giant buffer.

Comment: @Carcigenicate this crash report, from firebase analytic, I haven't found this issue on my test device yet.

Comment: Try using your computer, and print to the console the bufferSize. Once you have a concrete number to work with you can do the math and calculate how big of a buffer you're creating. If the size exceeds Android's default heap size, you might need to consider a lazy solution so the entirety isn't in memory all at once.

Answer (score 0):

Why calculate with big numbers?

```
    int bitsPerPixel = ImageFormat.getBitsPerPixel(ImageFormat.NV21);
    long sizeInBits = previewSize.getHeight() * previewSize.getWidth() * bitsPerPixel;
    int bufferSize = (int) Math.ceil(sizeInBits / 8.0d) + 1;
```

may be

```
    int bitsPerPixel = ImageFormat.getBitsPerPixel(ImageFormat.NV21);
    int bytePerPixel = bitsPerPixel >>> 3 + 1;
    int sizeInPixel = previewSize.getHeight() * previewSize.getWidth();
    int bufferSize = sizeInPixel * bytePerPixel;
```

You do not need the decimal conversion and stay within the int type range.

And at which line do you get the OOM-Error?

I do not know if you can ask the device for free memory and raise a message if available is less than calculated buffer size.

Comment: It is in the OP

Comment: byte[] byteArray = new byte[bufferSize];

Comment: I added device info when user got exception.

Comment: The crash device info shows 21 MB free space. With 3 byte for a pixel (I do not know the correct format size, please add debug output for bitsPerPixel and bufferSize) you may store 7340032 pixels (in optimal case; 21MB*1024*1024/3bytePerPixel). This may result in a 2700x2700 image size (sqrt(7340032)) or 3600x2025 (in 16:9 aspect). But there is some additional overhead within the VM.

Answer (score 0):

That piece of code comes from Google's Android vision library which is something I have frequently seen copied into peoples own projects.

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/blob/master/visionSamples/barcode-reader/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/samples/vision/barcodereader/ui/camera/CameraSource.java

This is a particularly memory hungry bit of code so is a likely candidate to fall over if you're device is low on memory. I recommend running a profiler over your app to see where the leak is.

For me, the leak was around the `CameraSource` which contains the mentioned code not being properly disposed of. Ensure you call `cameraSource!!.release()` on activity destroy else over time, every time you hit that activity, it slowly eats away more memory :)